# What can cause a BSOD when booting from CD, but not from Hard Disk?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bsod, boot-cd

We have a Windows XP machine that recently had a bad virus cleaned up off of it. It boots up just fine, however I suspect some windows files have been damaged and want to run a Repair from the original Windows CD.

The problem is, booting from the CD causes a BSOD with a Stop Message of `0x0000007B: INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`. The CD starts to load, and says its copying files, then after a minute or so it gives the BSOD.

We know this CD works on other machines so it's not the CD, but we tried some other boot CDs anyways with the same result. We've also tried running `chkdsk` and `fixmbr`, and even swapped the CD-ROM drive since it was making a weird clicking noise while reading a CD, and we thought that might be the problem.

I was going to wipe the HDD completely and reload the OS, but I don't want to turn the HDD  into an ugly paperweight if it can't read a boot disk to reload the OS. Afterall, it does still work even if a few programs crash unexpectedly at specific points.

So what can cause a computer to BSOD when booting from CD, but not from HDD? And is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: When the machine first starts to boot, press the special key (usually DEL, INSERT, or F2) to enter the BIOS setup program. There take a look at what devices are checked for booting. You might be able to change the order or remove any that aren't needed or aren't connected.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah i've seen a computer BSOD booting a CD. I keep  2 CD/DVD drives in a computer to deal with and test problems (BSOD aside).

It can be the CD(physically the CD, or the data when it was put onto the CD), it can be the CD Drive, it can be the cable, it can be the connector.

So try changing those things.

I see you haven't mentioned trying to change the cable or connector. (by connector, I mean the connector on the motherboard which the drive is connected to)

It's easy to try changing those if you already have 2 CD drives in there.

Comment: I already tried different CDs and a different CD drive. I can try a different cable, although I don't think it will make a difference since the CD does begin loading just fine, and successfully copies some files before giving a BSOD.

Comment: @Rachel  cables aren't just working perfectly vs not working at all.  They can be like that but there are in betweens. And the connector too. I've seen a computer that would BSOD until I moved the HDD to another connector (which was fine for some months until it started BSOD too.. so basically the motherboard but got some more life out of it by changing connector).  As for cables.. it could be SATA ones tend not to have that issue, maybe, but try it anyway.

Comment: @Rachel another change you can try is go to the computer where the CD works fine. Put that CD drive from the problem computer in it, and the CD.  See if it works, if yes, then that suggests maybe it's the motherboard of the computer with the issue.  If no, then the motherboard is fine and there's some other cause(like a cable). Point is, there's more troubleshooting you can do